# Set Timeout on CXF Proxy Client

Tags: cxf, jax-ws

I have a JAX-RS client in CXF created via JAXRSClientFactoryBean.create. How can I set the connection/receive timeouts?

I assume I need to get hold of the conduit but can't work out how to. This project is not using Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    HTTPClientPolicy clientConfig = WebClient.getConfig(service).getHttpConduit().getClient();
    clientConfig.setReceiveTimeout(10000);
```

Comment: Just realised this is the same as the previous answer. I thought it wasn't applicable because it wasn't for a bean but it turns out it works for both.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the code I use:

```java
service = JAXRSClientFactory.create(url, serviceClass, providers);
HTTPConduit conduit = WebClient.getConfig(service).getHttpConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
policy.setReceiveTimeout(300000); //5 minutes
conduit.setClient(policy);
```

Comment: I think I'm confused, are you talking about JAX-WS or JAX-RS? Your question says "I have a JAX-WS client" but "created via JAXRSClientFactoryBean", which creates JAX-RS clients?

Comment: OK, then for a CXF JAX-RS proxy client, my solution is what I've used for JAX-RS.